# Looking for an Idiom - Great Minds having great demons?

Tags: idiom-request

I think I recall some Idiom about great minds having great demons, but I cannot seem to find it anywhere online.

Does it not exist or am I misremembering a different one?

Comment: "great minds think alike" is the one I'm most familiar with

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Thanks, I know that one, but unfortunately it's not what I'm searching for

Answer (score 1):

No great mind has ever existed without a touch of madness - Aristotle